How Would I Interpret This Harmonically?

I'm sorry if this is a bit amateurish. However, this is a transcription of a song I heard online. The part that I am referring to is the instrument playing the thirds in the bass clef. The second to last staff. I'm not really sure how to interpret this. I assumed the 4th measure was just a I chord. But the staff on top seems to be playing thirds and then a fifth. Are these non chord tones?

Please add the title and composer.

"I assumed the 4th measure was just a I chord": the versions of this piece that I've found online have the chord (corresponding to the fourth staff here) changing less frequently than every measure, not twice every measure as shown here.  Can you link to the arrangement you're transcribing?

I'm transcribing Shin Gakki 2 by Masaki Kurihara.

https://youtu.be/Qa0W0X7Orlo?si=tPT94TH0A88go2v9

Ok thanks.  I haven't yet had time to give a close listen to that, but I listened long enough to see that your transcription isn't as wrong as I'd thought :-).  I will try to give it some more attention over the weekend.

The picture below is an analytical reduction of the score, including chord symbols, Roman numeral analysis, and non-chord tone labels (in red).

PT = passing tone
APT = accented passing tone
Esc = escape tone


The basic chord progression is
||:  DM7  D6  :||:  Em7  A7  :||,
or, more simply
||:     I     :||:  ii7  V7  :||.
The two D chords are a common way to make a lengthy chord more interesting by alternating between adding the 7 and the 6, thus DM7 and D6. The other two chords form a standard ii-V progression, which would most typically resolve back to I.
